# Android 4.3 BLE Pedometer profile

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have searched almost every bit on Google about this, but failed to get a satisfying response. I have an Android app to build which have to read and write data to a BLE pedometer (hardware). I have went through the Heart Rate Measurement example provided by Android, but it helped to the least to achieve, since I was unable to find any profile which may be near to the Pedometer or something similar. The Bluetooth SIG [website](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/GATT-Specification-Documents.aspx) also, don't have that profile listed.

I think I am not searching it in a right way, because its a pretty heavily used profile in devices like FitBit and Nike Fuel Band.

So, if someone can help me over this to start on this?

Answer (score 3):

I would think you thinking of the [running speed and cadence profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.running_speed_and_cadence.xml) which is basically the [running speed and cadence service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.running_speed_and_cadence.xml)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I am totally new to it, can you help me towards it?